# Proof for fixed point under specific circumstances

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Prove that every $f \in C(I, \mathbb{R})$ with $I := [-1, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f(I) \subseteq I$ has a fixed point.



This would be true if $f$ is a contraction on $I$, since then Banach's fixed point theorem would apply. For $f$ to be a contraction on $I$, the following has to be true: $$\forall a, b \in I: \exists L<1: \vert f(b)-f(a) \vert \leq L \cdot \vert b - a \vert$$ Moving the $\vert b - a \vert$ to the left side: $$\frac{\vert f(b) - f(a) \vert}{\vert b - a \vert} \leq L < 1$$ Estimating the left side using the supremum gives: $$\sup_{a, b \in I} \frac{\vert f(b) - f(a) \vert}{\vert b - a \vert} < 1$$ Intuitively this seems to be true, but I do not know how to prove it formally.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: I'm trying to prove this without topology.

Comment: Did you try to use IVT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 's no need for $f$ to be a contraction; set $g(x):=f(x)-x, x\in [a,b]$. Then $g(a)=f(a)-a\geq0$ and $g(b)=f(b)-b\leq0$, for $f([a,b])\subset[a,b]$, thus $g(a)g(b)\leq0$. By Bolzano Theorem $\exists ξ\in (a,b):g(ξ)=0\iff f(ξ)=ξ$. If $f$ is additionally a contraction, then the fixed is unique; let $x,x'$ two distinct fixed points of $f$. Then $|x-x'|=|f(x)-f(x')|\leq L|x-x'|\implies1\leq L$, which is false, because $L\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Once again, my intuition is telling me that both $g(a) \geq 0$ and $g(b) \leq 0$ must be true, but I can't quite understand why it is true. Would you mind elaborating on those?

Comment: Provided that $f([a,b])\subset [a,b]$, we get $a\leq f(a)\leq f(b)\leq b$, so $0\leq f(a)-a=g(a)$ and $g(b)=f(b)-b\leq 0$.

Comment: Why do we need the $g(a)g(b) \leq 0$, aren't $g(a) \geq 0$ and $g(b) \leq 0$ enough for IVT to be applicable?

Comment: Yes, it is enough for IVT in this case. I justed used Bolzano 's Theorem, which is equivalent here.